# Better way to put text under image?

Tags: html, css

I've had a hard time figuring this out. When I first tried to make the text stay under the picture it was `float`ed to left all the time. This code seems to work but I think I did something wrong because when you change `.resmontage ul` width from `70%` to `60%` all the pictures get smaller. They don't stay in the `width` or `height` I originally specified.

Why do I need to set `.resmontage img` to `width: 100%` to make it work with `.resmontage li`? If I remove width from `resmontage li` everything will screw up! I know you can use bootstrap but I prefer to do it myself.

```css
#bt {
  color: white;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-left: -8%;
}
.resmontage ul {
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  width: 70%;
  height: 25%;
  padding-left: 7%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  border-radius: 1%;
}
.resmontage li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 20%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 3%;
}
.resmontage img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 65%;
}
.hello {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: both;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="resmontage clearfix">
  <ul>
    <div id="bt">Games that will be released next month.</div>
    <li>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a5/Grand_Theft_Auto_V.png" />
      <div class="hello">Gta v</div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img src="http://media.steampowered.com/apps/valvestore/images/slider/store_image_02.png" />
      <div class="hello">CSGO</div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e0/Rocket_League_coverart.jpg" />
      <div class="hello">Rocket League</div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img src="http://blogs-images.forbes.com/erikkain/files/2014/12/The-Witcher-3-Wild-Hunt.jpg" />
      <div class="hello">Witcher 3</div>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, CSS is not a programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already set the `width` of the images by placing them in various `li`'s. When you specify them to have `width: 100%`, you are just telling them to take up their container, namely the `li`, which has a `width` of `20%`.

```css
#bt {
  color: white;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-left: -8%;
}
.resmontage ul {
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  width: 70%;
  height: 25%;
  padding-left: 7%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  border-radius: 1%;
}
.resmontage li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 20%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 3%;
}
.resmontage img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.hello {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div id="bt">Games that will be released next month.</div>
    <li>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a5/Grand_Theft_Auto_V.png" />
      <div class="hello">Gta v</div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img src="http://media.steampowered.com/apps/valvestore/images/slider/store_image_02.png" />
      <div class="hello">CSGO</div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e0/Rocket_League_coverart.jpg" />
      <div class="hello">Rocket League</div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img src="http://blogs-images.forbes.com/erikkain/files/2014/12/The-Witcher-3-Wild-Hunt.jpg" />
      <div class="hello">Witcher 3</div>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Zippiex it's ok. I amde some `margin`al improvements, but looks good to me